# Хэш таблицы в с++

Tags: c++, python, хеширование

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Автор этой книги уже не в первый раз добавляет сразу несколько значений во второе поле хеш-таблицы. Можно ли реализовать что то подобное на с++?

Answer (score 3):

Если я правильно понимаю ваш вопрос, вам нужен

```
unordered_map<string,set<string>>
```

или даже

```
unordered_map<string,unordered_set<string>>
```

Например:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    unordered_map<string,unordered_set<string>> m =
    {
        {"kone", {"id", "nv", "ut"}},
        {"ktwo", {"wa", "id", "mt"}},
        {"kthree", {"or", "nv", "ca"}}
    };

    for(const auto& s: m)
    {
        cout << s.first << ":";
        for(const auto& c: s.second) cout << " " << c;
        cout << "\n";
    }

}
```

Comment: А почему сразу нельзя использовать [std::unordered_multimap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multimap)?

Comment: @isnullxbh Для чего? у него как раз ключ - "первое поле" - уникален.

Comment: Извините, не совсем понимаю - что мешает вызвать ф-ию equal_range?

Comment: @isnullxbh Так, теперь уже я не понимаю... Или я изначально неверно трактую вопрос. Я его понял - как сделать так, чтоб в хеш-таблицу значением вносилось не одно значение, а некоторое их множество. Поясните, pls, ваше видение вопроса...

Comment: все, я Вас понял :) Я акцентировал внимание на выборе контейнера, в который можно вставить несколько элементов по одному и тому же ключу. Спасибо за разъяснение.